# MVC5 project with 2 errors that ocurr only when leaving a page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using VS Express 2013 for Web with an MVC5 project. I am using Firefox with Firebug enabled. When I run the application I momentarily see Firebug's toolbar icon read there are 2 errors. The errors only appear for a split second so I had to click enable Persist to retain them.

**ERROR #1:**

```
The connection to ws://localhost:61468/006ddcd224374fc08d1bf1f084312545/
arterySignalR/connect?transport=webSocketsconnectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAw
E%2FCl%2BsBAAAAr%2BL1sc0pfUucJd0c878FCgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAACtoiMe%2BbJR
4NDetzo8N8Pl0Q2%2BT3Tvaa5eSG2ms13tOgAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAABWmdgavHsH%2BqOP2eDJfCVWM
pi1BjIrZAeB5ipr95pJMTAAAADLFakFumFaKP3P1ac870jb4lRb26ZFNSYTqg177H7iuFnAM7lBIRTb
GL9sNaSjPZFAAAAAQNNdEXsDdbdEbwompKByoZADTIppqRpGZYpUm1I1kg4F7VYNpu0Bhyo3JM7i4qEKL
6paHsP%2FbVLc8ENAce3CVQ%3D%3D&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A59655
%2FAccount%2FRequestAccount&browserName=Firefox&tid=8
was interrupted while the page was loading.

...thCredentials:f.withCredentials},url:o,type:f.ajaxDataType==="jsonp"?
"GET":"POST...
```

**ERROR #2:**

```
browserLink (line 62)
no element found
```

There is a link in the right pane of Firebug and it contains:

```
http://localhost:61468/006ddcd224374fc08d1bf1f084312545/arterySignalR
/abort?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAr
%2BL1sc0pfUucJd0c878FCgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAACtoiMe%2BbJR4NDetzo8N8P
l0Q2%2BT3Tvaa5eSG2ms13tOgAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAABWmdgavHsH%2BqOP2eDJf
CVWMpi1BjIrZAeB5ipr95pJMTAAAADLFakFumFaKP3P1ac870jb4lRb26ZFNSYTqg177
H7iuFnAM7lBIRTbGL9sNaSjPZFAAAAAQNNdEXsDdbdEbwompKByoZADTIppqRpGZYpUm
1I1kg4F7VYNpu0Bhyo3JM7i4qEKL6paHsP%2FbVLc8ENAce3CVQ%3D%3D
&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A59655%2FAccount
%2FRequestAccount&browserName=Firefox
```

The only time I see these errors is when I click on a link or a button that causes the page to reload or navigate to a different page, even just a page refresh causes the errors - but they disappear immediately as soon as the page begins loading.

Something related to Ajax? Seems like such a stupid post, but I just can't see anything wrong in the code.

**UPDATE:**

There are some posts on this question that infer there is a problem with the content or markup. Since this is happening on every page, I went into _Layout.cshtml and step by step removed all sections of code, yet the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not a problem with your code, it is a new feature in VS 2013 call Browser Link.  You can disable it by unchecking the Enable browser link in the following image:

[image]

I haven't used it very much, but for more information about Browser Link and its uses, the following [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) covers it pretty well.

**EDIT**

The blog I linked was for the RTM version of VS 2013, so [here is an article](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link) from asp.net that provides a little more info past the RTM version.

Comment: Sure enough. Disabling Browser Link resolved the errors. I'll read the blog. Thx Tommy.